# How do I enter a batch of payments in the Square-Connect API

Tags: square-connect

If I have a custom business accounting system, and I want to drop a series of month end payments onto the Square-connect API using the stored card information, that is, a non-swipe payment.  How can I do this?

I see where I can list payments, but not create new ones via the API.

Right now, it is a manual process, a person takes the report and types in all the data into Square's "Manual payment" site.  Of course, that is time consuming and prone to error.

Thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the E-commerce APIs to create transactions with end users, or if you have the card information stored as a card on file, you can charge those transactions in batch. See [processing recurring payments](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/processing-recurring-payments-ruby).

Comment: Dropping a batch of payments is a pretty common (read: universal) feature of payment processors.  If they are going to play in this space, do they have plans to support such a thing?

Comment: Is there at least a way to mangle the urls on their manual payment website so that I can script it?